# ¿Como puedo hacer correr este dll?

Tags: java, serialport

Buenas tardes me pasaron un código que conecta una bascula con java por medio del puerto serial ya importe todas las librerías que el programa necesita, en especifico la librería serialPort.jar con su libreria libSerialPort.dll

Al seguir la secuencia del programa me marca un error de

> *link  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Desarrollo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\pesar\libSerialPort.dll:
>   Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform*

Les dejo el código aquí abajo consta de tres archivos los cuales son :

-Configuracion

```
package Controlador;

 public class Configuracion {
private final String archivo = "Configuracion.txt";//Archivo de        donde se sacaran los datos de configuracion
private String PuertoCOM;
private int Delay;
private boolean OcultarConsola;
private String ultimoCaracter;
private String PuertoSerial;
private String url;
private String caracterSolicitud;
private String impresora;
private boolean MandarCaracterPeticion;

public void CargarConfiguracion() {
    PuertoCOM = this.obtenerValorParametro("Puerto");
    if(PuertoCOM.equals("")){
        System.out.println("Error al leer el valor Puerto, se asignarán valores predeterminados");
        PuertoCOM = "COM1";
    }

    PuertoSerial = this.obtenerValorParametro("Serial");
    if(PuertoSerial.equals("")){
        System.out.println("Error al leer el valor Serial, se asignarán valores predeterminados");
        PuertoSerial = "9600";
    }

    try{
        Delay = Integer.parseInt(this.obtenerValorParametro("Delay"));                    
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("Error al leer el valor Delay, se asignarán valores predeterminados");
        Delay = 10;            
    }        

    ultimoCaracter = this.obtenerValorParametro("UltimoCaracter");
    if(ultimoCaracter.equals("")){
        System.out.println("Error al leer el valor UltimoCaracter, se asignarán valores predeterminados");
        ultimoCaracter = "R";
    }

    url = this.obtenerValorParametro("URL");
    if(url.equals("")){
        System.out.println("Error al leer el valor UltimoCaracter, se asignarán valores predeterminados");
        url = "http://localhost/RegistroPesajeWS";
    }

    impresora = this.obtenerValorParametro("Impresora");
    if(impresora.equals("")){
        System.out.println("Error al leer el valor Impresora, se asignarán valores predeterminados");
        impresora = "EPSON";
    } 

    caracterSolicitud = this.obtenerValorParametro("CaracterPeticion");
    if(caracterSolicitud.equals("")){
        System.out.println("Error al leer el valor caracterSolicitud, se asignarán valores predeterminados");
        caracterSolicitud = "P";
    } 

    OcultarConsola = (this.obtenerValorParametro("OcultarConsola").equals("1"));   
    MandarCaracterPeticion = (this.obtenerValorParametro("MandarCaracterPeticion").equals("1"));
}

private String obtenerValorParametro(String parametro){
    String valor = "";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.archivo));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {                
            if(sCurrentLine.contains(parametro + ":")){//Cuando se encuentra el parametro a buscar
                int indice = sCurrentLine.indexOf(parametro+":");//Se obtiene el indice donde empieza el texto del parametro
                int lengthParametro = parametro.length()+1;//Se obtiene la longitud en caracteres del parametro                                        
                valor = sCurrentLine.substring(indice+lengthParametro);
                //System.out.println("El valor debería de ser: "+valor);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return valor;
}

public String getPuertoCOM() {
    return PuertoCOM;
}

public int getDelay() {
    return Delay;
}

public boolean isOcultarConsola() {
    return OcultarConsola;
}

public String getPuertoSerial() {
    return PuertoSerial;
}     

public String getUltimoCaracter() {
    return ultimoCaracter;
}

public void setUltimoCaracter(String ultimoCaracter) {
    this.ultimoCaracter = ultimoCaracter;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getCaracterSolicitud() {
    return caracterSolicitud;
}

public void setCaracterSolicitud(String caracterSolicitud) {
    this.caracterSolicitud = caracterSolicitud;
}        

public String getImpresora() {
    return impresora;
}

public void setImpresora(String impresora) {
    this.impresora = impresora;
}   

public boolean isMandarCaracterPeticion() {
    return MandarCaracterPeticion;
}

public void setMandarCaracterPeticion(boolean MandarCaracterPeticion) {
    this.MandarCaracterPeticion = MandarCaracterPeticion;
}        
}
```

-Pedir datos Datos

```
 private final Enviar_datos enviar;
private Configuracion configuracion = new Configuracion();
private String puertoSerial = "";
private SerialPort puerto;
private Parameters settings;
private Com com1;

public Pedir_Datos_Bascula(Configuracion conf) {
    this.configuracion = conf;
    enviar = new Enviar_datos(this.configuracion);
}

public String hacerPeticionPesaje() {
    try {
        puerto = new SerialPort();
        List<String> listaPuertos;
        String recibido = "";
        String caracter = "";
        puertoSerial = "";

        listaPuertos = puerto.getFreeSerialPort();
        puertoSerial = this.configuracion.getPuertoCOM();
        for (String string : listaPuertos) {//Se recorren todos los puertos
            puertoSerial = string;
            if (string.equals(this.configuracion.getPuertoCOM())) {//Si se encuentra el puerto marcado en la configuracion, se trabaja con este puerto                             
                break;
            }
        }
        settings = new Parameters();
        settings.setPort(puertoSerial);
        settings.setBaudRate(configuracion.getPuertoSerial());//Se asigna el puerto serial que viene en la configuracion                                     

        com1 = new Com(settings);
        if (configuracion.isMandarCaracterPeticion()) {
            com1.sendSingleData(configuracion.getCaracterSolicitud());
            com1.sendSingleData(Character.toString((char) 13));
            com1.sendSingleData(Character.toString((char) 10));
        }

        int contador = 0;
        recibido = "";
        while (!caracter.equals(configuracion.getUltimoCaracter())) {

            caracter = com1.receiveSingleString();
            recibido += caracter;
            contador++;
            if (contador > 100) {
                return "";
            }
        }

        if (!recibido.equals("")) {
            //System.out.println(recibido);//cbc
            String pesoNeto = recibido;
            enviar.setPeso_neto(pesoNeto);
            this.terminarLeerDatos();
            return this.convertirPesaje(pesoNeto);
            //enviar.converir_datos();
        } else {
            this.terminarLeerDatos();
            return "";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.terminarLeerDatos();
        System.out.println("Run: " + e);
        return null;
    }
}

private String convertirPesaje(String peso_neto) {
    String peso = "";
    for (int x = 0; x < peso_neto.length(); x++) {
        if (peso_neto.charAt(x) == '0') {
            peso += "0";
        } else if (peso_neto.charAt(x) == '1') {
            peso += "1";
        } else if (peso_neto.charAt(x) == '2') {
            peso += "2";
        } else if (peso_neto.charAt(x) == '3') {
            peso += "3";
        } else if (peso_neto.charAt(x) == '4') {
            peso += "4";
        } else if (peso_neto.charAt(x) == '5') {
            peso += "5";
        } else if (peso_neto.charAt(x) == '6') {
            peso += "6";
        } else if (peso_neto.charAt(x) == '7') {
            peso += "7";
        } else if (peso_neto.charAt(x) == '8') {
            peso += "8";
        } else if (peso_neto.charAt(x) == '9') {
            peso += "9";
        } else if (peso_neto.charAt(x) == '.') {
            peso += ".";
        } else {
            //robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_9);
        }

    }
    return peso;
}

public void terminarLeerDatos() {
    try {
        puerto.closePortC(puertoSerial);
        com1.closePortC(puertoSerial);
        //puerto.closePortC(puertoSerial);            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error terminarLeerDatos: " + e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

El archivo externo de configuración es archivo de block de notas lo que trae lo pondre abajo

```
Puerto:COM4
Delay:10
OcultarConsola:1
Serial:9600
UltimoCaracter:k
CaracterPeticion:P
Impresora:EPSONL355
MandarCaracterPeticion:0
```

Cuando empiezo a seguir los pasos me sale el error del principio .
Mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo hacer que corra con ese mismo archivo?¿Tendría que utilizar otra librería?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que te ocurre es que estás intentando cargar una DLL de 32 bits en una JVM de 64 bits. La única solución que tienes es utilizar una DLL y una JVM con la misma arquitectura (ambas para 32 bits o ambas para 64 bits).

Comment: ok entiendo y el jvm se puede descargar la de 32 en una maquina de 64

Comment: Si, como casi todos los programas de 32 bits, una JVM de 32 bits puede correr sobre un Sistema Operativo de 64 bits. Ahora, el problema está en que, si mal no recurdo, a partir de la versión 9 de Java no hay JDK para 64 bits.

Comment: entonces tendría que busca runa versión de java mas antigua para descargar el jdk y poder correr el programa con la jvm y la dll

Comment: Seguramente, o compilar una dll para 64 bits, si te es posible